# Как вскрыть узлы DOM

Tags: python, html, beautiful-soup, selenium-webdriver, dom

[image: Пример]

Доброго времени суток!

Вопрос как вытащить данные которые скрываются?

Что я пробовал:

- Прыжок в верхний div тег hj4, bs4 и selenium видят только 180 таких карточек, т.е всего 4 тега hj4 в каждом по 36 vi1 ... , хочу узнать как все таки распарсить их все.
  Спасибо